# Copying and moving child node with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xsl script that transforms an incorrect xml, thereby moving the *port* children to the correct parent *host*.

```
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="host">
        <xsl:variable name="hostname" select="@name"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//host/port[@parent=$hostname]">
                 <xsl:sort select="@name" data-type="text" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Example of incorrect xml (some ports are not placed under their parent)

```
    <hosts>
      <host modelID="1" name="H2">
         <port ID="H2.Port1" name="Port1" parent="H2" speed="100"/>
         <port ID="H2.Port2" name="Port2" parent="H2" speed="100"/>
         <port ID="H1.Port1" name="Port1" parent="H1" speed="100"/>
      </host>
      <host modelID="1" name="H1"/>
    </hosts>
```

Desired output.

```
    <hosts>
       <host modelID="1" name="H2">
          <port ID="H2.Port1" name="Port1" parent="H2" speed="100"/>
          <port ID="H2.Port2" name="Port2" parent="H2" speed="100"/>
       </host>
       <host modelID="1" name="H1">
          <port ID="H1.Port1" name="Port1" parent="H1" speed="100"/>
       </host>
    </hosts>
```

Now, the input has changed so that it includes a new *port* element. I want to change the script to take care of this and include the new element in the output.
New desired output.

```
   <hosts>
      <host modelID="1" name="H2">
         <ports>
            <port ID="H2.Port1" name="Port1" parent="H2" speed="100"/>
            <port ID="H2.Port2" name="Port2" parent="H2" speed="100"/>
         </ports> 
       </host>
       <host modelID="1" name="H1">
          <ports>
             <port ID="H1.Port1" name="Port1" parent="H1" speed="100"/>
          </ports>
       </host>
    </hosts>
```

I was hoping that I would only need to change the line

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//host/port[@parent=$hostname]">
```

to

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//host/ports/port[@parent=$hostname]">
```

Why does this not work, and what need I do instead?

Comment: Do you have a changed input that already includes a `ports` element? Or do you need to create a `ports` elements in the result of the XSLT transformation?

Comment: Good point! I do have a changed input including the <ports> element

Comment: "Why does this not work" <-- What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath you use in `apply-templates` applies to the *input* document, not to the one you want to create. So it looks like you need to do this:

```
<xsl:template match="host">
    <xsl:variable name="hostname" select="@name"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <ports>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//host/ports/port[@parent=$hostname]">
                 <xsl:sort select="@name" data-type="text" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </ports>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: SOrry, forget to mention that I do have a changed input containing the <ports> element. Will edit the question.

Comment: @user1859309 Please see my update, and if this doesn't solve the issue, please tell me in what way it's not working.

Comment: Works as intended. much appreciated